# Why are there two places to specify the App Icon File?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

The App Icon File is defined in the plist as well as in the Info Tab of the target.

Is there any reason for this or is it just redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just two different places for the exact same setting. Changing it at one place will change it in the other location.

The same is true for the "Bundle Identifier", "Version" and "Build" fields in the Summary tab, which will change the values in the Info.plist.

Actually quite every piece of information present in the "Summary" tab is just another way to present common information present in the Info.plist file, it is just a more readable presentation of the exact same info. And same for the "Info" tab, which present the Info.plist keys directly, and extract some special keys like Document Types, UTIs and URL Types in a separate view: everything in there is just another presentation of the Info.plist file too.

---

**Special note for the "Icon" attribute**: there are **various ways to define the application icons in the Info.plist keys** due to evolution across the various SDKs. And **the icon in the "Summary" tab only affect the latest way to define icons**.

- At start there was only one key `CFBundleIconFile` of type string that defined a unique icon name. Simple enough.
- Then another key `CFBundleIconFiles` has been added to accepted a list (NSArray) of icons, to support multiple resolutions and usages (Search icon, etc)
- Finally, in iOS5, another key was introduced again called `CFBundleIcons` that is now a dictionary that allows you to list each icon file and its associated purpose (Newsstand icon, Search icon, App Icon…)

For more details, read the [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html) which explains the differences in detail.

Comment: Actually I thought so too, but changing it in one place does not change it in the other - at least not all the time - really strange behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Removing the items in one place causes them to be removed at the other place as well. So I guess it is redundant. Also dragging and dropping the icon files into the "App Icons" slots under the target's "Summary" tab achieves the same effect.

Comment: but one can specify different values - strangely enough